# Not able to run Harmonize flow in Data Hub Framework MarkLogic

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-dhf, ml-gradle

I am trying to run Harmonize flow using Gradle in DHF and getting the below error-

```
RESTAPI-SRVEXERR: (err:FOER0000) Extension Error:  code: 404 message: Not 
Found document: The requested flow was not found
2018-06-29 11:57:22.627 Notice: in 
/marklogic.rest.resource/flow/assets/resource.xqy, at 72:14,
2018-06-29 11:57:22.627 Notice: in function() as item()*() [1.0-ml]
2018-06-29 11:57:22.627 Notice:   $entity-name = "Order"
2018-06-29 11:57:22.627 Notice:   $flow-name = "HarmonizeFlow"
2018-06-29 11:57:22.627 Notice:   $flow-type = "harmonize"
2018-06-29 11:57:22.627 Notice:   $flow = ()
```

Data Hub Framework version -2.0.4
MarkLogic Version-9.0.3

The files for harmonize flow has been created successfully but not able to run the flow.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you deployed your modules with the mlLoadModules task?  They need to be copied from your filesystem into MarkLogic.

Comment: it helped me after i deployed the modules.

Answer (score 2):

[DHF requires MarkLogic version 9.0-5](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub#version-support) or higher. Earlier versions of the DHF included the flows and REST endpoints, but they are now included in MarkLogic itself.